# PHPSpec: Configuration of Output Format

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, phpspec

I am using PHPSpec, but whenever a test fails I get the following:

[image]

It does say, where my tests fail, but it does not output what exactly was returned, thus being rather unhelpful.

I tried to format the output by creating a **phpspec.yml** file and putting it in my project folder, but right now it only looks like this:

```
formatter.name: dot
```

Is there any other way to configure phpspec, so that I get an output, that is actually helpful? (By showing what was returned and what expected?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run phpspec in a verbose mode to get more output:

```
bin/phpspec -v
```

You can increase the verbosity with:

```
bin/phpspec -vv
```

or:

```
bin/phpspec -vvv
```